# Retrieve the url from a yql result

Tags: javascript, yql

I have been trying to understand how to return links from yql results, but so far the only thing im getting is [object Object] and i am not getting anywhere so far, could you care to explain to me why is this happening? All I want is to display the results as links.

```
<div id="funfacts"> 
</div> 
<script> 
function funfacts(o){ 
  var facts = document.getElementById('funfacts'); 
  if(facts){ 
    var data = o.query.results.a; 
    var out = document.createElement('a'); 
    out.className = 'fact'; 
    facts.appendChild(out); 
    out.innerHTML = data.join("<br />"); 
  } 
} 
</script> 
<script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20href%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fcid-a59bebc211b678a6.office.live.com%2Fbrowse.aspx%2FPublic%2Fhi5'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fa%5B%40id%3D%22download%22%5D'%0D%0A&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=funfacts"></script>
```

I hope this example is enough for understanding, all i am trying to do is for it to display the list of urls from that page, however it only returns a list of [object Object] lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a console.log on the return object you'll see that results is actually an array with three arrays within it.  Thus to get the url you would actually need to do something like o.query.results.a[n].href

```
results: Object
a: Array[3]
0: Object
href: "http://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pXKbPqGSt2TkgDjLyAOoYLWSPBnYLdxVtOHoR4W0sERdCyCncGu4LR8Bg4e81W…"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/ye5Cr/3/)

Comment: I have successfully managed to make the links appear while replacing the data.join with [data[0].href].join, however, is there anyway to make the [n] as for any number? For example, imagine that i have 100 links, it will be a lot of work writting down all 100 data[n].href! Isn't there any "hack" to tell the script to display all the results that exist?

Comment: you can do a for loop on o.query.results.a where the termination would be o.query.result.a.length

Comment: However, whenever i try to place o.query.result.a.100 or [100], a syntax error occurs, or shouldnt it be done that way?

Comment: well, the problem is what if you don't have 100 links in the query?  you can do the following: for(var i=0; i<o.query.result.a.length; i++){ alert(o.query.result.a[i].href); }  This will loop through all results and alert you with the href.

Comment: Makes sense, the problem is, i am having a hard time trying to implement that in the code, would you mind to answer the final result?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Can you please elaborate the final result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: can you paste your code on jsfiddle so i can see what you are attempting to do besides the above code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/27JLL/3/  here is the update jsfiddle link.  however, you would need to include mootools and mootools more (JSONP) for it to work.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see any change, have you modified anything?

Comment: I did, the only change i notice was the "function = funfacts (o)" that i wrote wrong, but i dont see your idea of the "for(var i=0; i<o.query.result.a.length; i++){ alert(o.query.result.a[i].href); }" there..

Comment: This is what i am refering to.  http://jsfiddle.net/27JLL/6/  Hope this is enough to get you going.  If this is the right answer, would you please be kind and vote my answer is the right answer?  I would appreciate it.

Comment: Oh man, perfect. You were a tremendous help, and i already had voted for it, but for some reason it didnt record the vote, here you go! would like to rep but i dont have enough yet, as soon as i have it, you can count on another vote, thanks a million!